Direct stored procedure table-valued output to a table
I have a stored procedure that (probably) has something like
SELECT f1, f2, f3 
FROM someTable

(more complex, but complexity is not relevant for the question).
The table is not a table valued output parameter, it is just a statement.
And, I don't have access to modify stored procedure to make a table valued type parameter.
When I run it, I want to be able to direct that output into a temporary table.
Something like you would do if writing a select yourself in this way
SELECT f1, f2, f3 
INTO #TEMPTABLE
FROM someTable 

My immediate guess is to do something like
SELECT * 
FROM (EXEC sp_MyStoredProcedure)

But, it is incorrect. Can I get what I am looking for without creating a table valued type ?
I also don't want to define the table before the INSERT as the procedure has too many columns.

Side note: you should not use the sp_ prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has reserved that prefix for its own use (see Naming Stored Procedures), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. It's also bad for your stored procedure performance. It's best to just simply avoid sp_ and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Check out: INSERT EXEC-construct which does what you want. I'm not sure why you mention table valued type though, because you cannot modify those when you use them as procedure parameters

For INSERT EXEC-construct I will need to know the columns ahead of time and specify them for the temp table.  there are too many and I would like to avoid doing it if possible

Ok, this is a detail you might wanna mention ahead of time. You can use openquery against yourself and execute the procedure there, but this solution usually nears the Whiskey Tango Foxtrot-territory.

"I don't have access to modify stored procedure to make a table valued type parameter." This wouldn't help you anyway; table type parameters can only be defined as READONLY. You would be unable to pass an ("empty") table type parameter to the procedure and have it INSERT the data into said parameter and pass it back to the calling SQL as an OUTPUT parameter.

"there are too many" Honestly, I find this a hard pill to swallow. Very likely you only need to write the CREATE statement once, as then the task you need to do is done, or you write the code so you can reuse it again in the future. Sure, it might add 3-4 minutes to your total time to complete the work, but writing this question probably took just as long.

@ThomA, true.  I ended up doing this.

You can execute the stored procedure into the temp table after it has been created
CREATE TABLE #Temp(SomeID PRMARY KEY, SomeValue INT)
INSERT #Temp EXEC StoredProcedure @ID


I would have to know the fields with types.  There are too many, and hence, I'd like to avoid doing this

@DmitriyRyabin Then you have a problem with your design. Open a new question describing what the SP should do and we can give you better options. But, in principle, "I don't want to need to know the table definition" is a glaringly huge code-smell.
